# Call method from string

Tags: python, oop, getattr, method-dispatch

If I have a Python class, and would like to call a function from it depending on a variable, how would I do so? I imagined following could do it:

```
class CallMe: # Class

   def App(): # Method one

      ...

   def Foo(): # Method two

      ...

variable = "App" # Method to call

CallMe.variable() # Calling App()
```

But it couldn't. Any other way to do this?

Comment: How do you decide what value to place in `variable`?

Comment: I would use an argument passed to the file. :)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can do this:

```
getattr(CallMe, variable)()
```

[getattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) is a builtin method, it returns the value of the named attributed of object. The value in this case is a method object that you can call with ()

Comment: Could you please tell me what do I do if I have a string whose value is `"CallMe"`?

Comment: The same approach works on the module.  If `CallMe` was in a module imported as `m`, then `getattr(m, 'CallMe')` would return the class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use getattr, or you can assign bound or unbound methods to the variable.  Bound methods are tied to a particular instance of the class, and unbound methods are tied to the class, so you have to pass an instance in as the first parameter.

e.g.

```
class CallMe:
    def App(self):
        print "this is App"

    def Foo(self):
        print "I'm Foo"

obj = CallMe()

# bound method:
var = obj.App
var()         # prints "this is App"

# unbound method:
var = CallMe.Foo
var(obj)      # prints "I'm Foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class has been declared as an "old-style class".  I recommend you make all your classes be "new-style classes".

The difference between the old and the new is that new-style classes can use inheritance, which you might not need right away.  But it's a good habit to get into.

Here is all you have to do to make a new-style class: you use the Python syntax to say that it inherits from "object".  You do that by putting parentheses after the class name and putting the name *object* inside the parentheses.  Like so:

```
class CallMe(object): # Class

   def App(): # Method one

      ...

   def Foo(): # Method two

      ...
```

As I said, you might not need to use inheritance right away, but this is a good habit to get into.  There are several questions here on StackOverflow to the effect of "I'm trying to do *X* and it doesn't work" and it turns out the person had coded an old-style class.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not look like python, may be you want to do like this?

```
class CallMe:

    def App(self): #// Method one
        print "hello"

    def Foo(self): #// Method two
        return None

    variable = App #// Method to call

CallMe().variable() #// Calling App()
```