# evaluating a variable as a method name in python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium 2 with Webdriver.  I would like to pass in my desired environment as part of a set of test data. My code looks like this:

```
    capability = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
```

And works correctly.  But I would like to pass the "FIREFOX" in from a variable, kind of like this:

```
    TestParameters['Environment']="FIREFOX"
    capability = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.TestParameters['Environment']
```

But I get this error

```
AttributeError: type object 'DesiredCapabilities' has no attribute 'TestParameters'
```

What can I do to evaluate the variable contents as a method name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call class method from variable in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855558/call-class-method-from-variable-in-python)

Comment: Actually... this one is a closer dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code tries to access the attribute by the variable *name* instead of the variable *value*:

```
capability = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.TestParameters['Environment']
```

As the error message says, this evaluates the `TestParameters` attribute of `webdriver.DesiredCapabilites`.  Which it doesn't have.

What you want is to evaluate the attribute whose name is the value of `TestParameters['Environment']`:

```
capabilityAttributeName = TestParameters['Environment']
capability = getattr(webdriver.DesiredCapabilities, capabilityAttributeName)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  I knew there had to be some simple bit of special sauce to make that work.